# Why is maximum work done for reversible paths in isothermal expansion and not minimum work done?

Tags: thermodynamics

Work done is given by $W = -P_{ext}dV $ according to convention.

Which should mean that in cases of expansion, work done on the system would be negative. If work done is negative, isn't it wrong to say that work done in isothermal reversible process is maximum? Because in irreversible expansions, area covered is smaller but then, if the value is negative, then wouldn't it be that minimum work is done in case of reversible isothermal expansion and maximum for irreversible case?

[image]

Image for clarification. This image is for expansion. The dark gray area is for irreversible process and the light gray + dark gray is the work done by reversible process. Clearly reversible process has higher area and hence higher negative value.

Comment: What is the maximum of -5 and -8?

Comment: The work done *by the system* is maximum.

Comment: -5 is bigger than -8. Magnitude wise, 8 is bigger than 5.

Comment: @BuckThorn Ahh, is that what they actually mean?

Comment: Well, in the opposite direction (compression) you would say that the work *done by the surroundings* is least for a reversible process.

Comment: @BuckThorn No, I think that work done on the system for compression would still be minimum for reversible process because for irreversible process, the higher pressure curve would cover a bigger area than reversible process curve.

Comment: @BuckThorn Apologies, I thought you were saying that work done on system was maximum for reversible isothermal process.

Comment: The equation you gave  is for the work done *on* the system.  The work done *by* the system is $+P_{ext}dV$.

Comment: @ChetMiller my teacher told me that work done is maximum in reversible isothermal process compared to any other process. is this correct?or it needs more conditions to be included?

Comment: For the same volume change, more work is done at constant pressure.

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about the work done in the above equation,

> $W=-P_{ext}dV$ ,

the negative sign only tells us about whether the **work is done by the system or work is done on the system**. So during expansion the work comes out to be negative indicating *the work is done by the system*. It is just a physical notion and has nothing to do with the actual magnitude, as we have for acceleration or velocity where negative indicates the opposite direction, just like that.